# Crystal scanning all record regardless of date parameters passed

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created a report that has a start and end date parameter. These are created and referenced in the where query. They work fine in the main report, but even when I link them to the subreport, the subreport keeps looking through all the fields and take too long to launch. Any suggestion how can I make the sub-report too look for records in the specified range only?

I have created the links with the Select data in subreport based on field, unchecked and the select expert formula is set as shown below

```
{Command.program_code} = {?Pm-Command.program_code} and
{@appointment_date} in {?Pm-?from} to {?Pm-?to} and
{Command.SITEID} = {?Pm-Command.SITEID}
```

Comment: have you checked are you getting any data in the fields that are linked from main report to sub report?

Comment: Yes, I checked and it is passing the parameters values. However, I was able to go around this issue by grouping, and using drilldowngrouplevel =0; in Section expert. This allowed me to initially only show group name and summary and drill down if decided to check all other data